# MongoDB database entries

Tags: mongodb

I am new to programming and I am trying to create a project that lists a class schedule for each day of the week. As I am new to mongodb, this may be a fairly trivial question for most.

when I am creating my database in mongodb atlas, how do I input specific start and end times for each class? for example, How would I input a class that is on Monday, Wednesday, Friday from 8:00am to 9:00am?

all of the docs I have found have shown me how to create a start and end time that begins at zero to record the total time something took, but I can't seem to find anything that allows me to input things at specific times on specific days.

Comment: something similar to this? 
https://mongoplayground.net/p/CiglGb8ezAQ

Comment: @indybee, For weekdays you should better use numbers 0..6 (or 1..7) where Monday is the first day of the week, according to ISO-8601. It will save you a lot of functions for conversion.

Comment: How to model this will greatly depend on how you will use the data.  Possibilies include storing the offset of each class session midnight Sunday for ease of creating a weekly calendar, or use and array that holds the exact datetime for each individual class session.  There are just 2 potential ideas, there are a great many ways it might be done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.